# CSS class specificity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 I'm trying to override the carousel control's CSS for a particular carousel with out affecting all carousels so I have my markup like this.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left chart-previous"></span>
```

So I've created a CSS rule with this selector:

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left .chart-previous
```

To override Bootstrap's selector:

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left
```

Bootstrap's selector gives me a specificity of 0,0,2,0 where as my custom CSS rule gives a specificity of 0,0,3,0, at least according to this site http://specificity.keegan.st/.  So given that why does the Bootstrap CSS rule still override my custom rule?

Comment: Should it not be `.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left.chart-previous` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space in a selector is a [*descendant* combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Your span is a member of both `glyphicon-chevron-left` and `chart-previous`.

Since it isn't a descendant of an element that is a member of `glyphicon-chevron-left`, your selector doesn't match it so it doesn't matter how specific it is.

Remove the extra space.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for the tip and the selector documentation really helps clear a lot up for me.